# Instagram realtime API does not return content IDs?

Tags: instagram

**Current scenario**

I have build an application that harvest Instagram images from a specific hashtag.
I use the pagination to fetch all images, and store the data (not the images) locally in a database. The first invocation of the app harvest all images. Subsequent invocations only harvest those newer than the newest image in the local database. Otherwise I would need to make thousands of request to page through all images on popular tags. And that would need to be done every few minutes, if images where to appear without too much delay in the app.
The problem that arises is that when users put tags on old images, these images are then not fetched by my app - because of the only-fetch-new-images performance construct.

**Attempt at solution**

I looked at the realtime API, but is seems to me it is constructed in a way that makes it unsuable. This is what it sends in a realtime update for a tag:

```
{
    "subscription_id": "2",
    "object": "tag",
    "object_id": "nofilter",
    "changed_aspect": "media",
    "time": 1297286541
}
```

I would have thought that there would be a list of media IDs, representing the new/changed content, from which I could fetch the actual content - but there is not.
My current solution is to fetch new content every few minutes, and then doing full rescans every hour. This is suboptimal both from a user, and a performance perspective.

**Question**

Is it really not possible to do in a more elegant way? I appreciate that Instagram does not send the full content in the realtime update, but sending the IDs should not be a problem in terms of payload-size. It seems like the API is pretty useless in this regards - the only use-case I can think of, where it would be of any use, is for a "There is new content on you hashtag watch" nofications.

Best,
Torben

Comment: How did you solve it? I have exactly the same problem (get newly tagged content). I really can't understand rationale behind such design of the realtime API, it's pretty much useless.

Comment: I have not resolved it. My current solution is to do "new content search" every 1 minute or so (only a few requests). I then do a secondary full scan of the tag once every 30 minutes, which adds images that have been tagged since last scan, and deletes images that are no longer present in the feed (otherwise you get dead images in your feed). This means there is some delay in getting some of the new images, and getting rid of the dead images, and it is fairly heavy. How often you would do these full rescans depend on the number of images.

Comment: I currently only have a few thousand images. But suppose we have 50000 images with an approx page size of 15 images thats 3000+ requests per rescan... There are no official limits for Instagram request (except "be reasonable"), but I imagine you could fairly quickly get greylisted. I have implemented a short delay between requests to avoid carpet bombing their servers.

Comment: Thanks for helpful response. I guess I'd be doing something similar, though I don't need to worry about dead images. Hope folks at Instagram will improve their API in meantime

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I've logged a bug with instagram but haven't heard anything back yet. Did you ever get the realtime api to work in a useful way?

Comment: @Longstreet: No, I didn't use the realtime API at all. I used the "frequent fetch new, rare scan for older pics" method as I described in the comment from September 17t 13:00.

Answer (score 0):

What I do with geography search is that everytime I get a update package I query the recent geography endpoint. This works quite well. Im guessing thats the idea with tag subscription aswell, have you tried querying the recent instagrams tag endpoint?

```
/tags/[tag-name]/media/recent
```

Comment: media/recent is the endpoint I'm already querying. Old images that gets a tag attached is not moved to the start of the "recent list", so you have to do a full rescan through all the pages, to find the new image(s).

Answer (score 0):

Paginate the recent media for a tag with the `min_tag_id` parameter to sort the result based on when it was tagged and not when the photo was taken. We use this in combination with the realtime api at [silarapp.com](http://silarapp.com) and it works fine.

From the [Instagram Api Documenation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) (my emphasis):

> Get a list of recently tagged media. Note that this **media is ordered by when the media was tagged** with this tag, rather than the order it was posted. **Use the max_tag_id and min_tag_id parameters in the pagination response to paginate** through these objects. Can return a mix of image and video types.